Small split on the bottom of the wooden stud on a load bearing wall
The pipes of my water heater leaked. The heater was in a small closet in the balcony and the wall had gotten wet. The plumber unhooked and removed the heater. A drywall guy, removed the drywall and changed it and changed the insulation inside. When he removed the drywall, I saw a small split on the very bottom of one of the wooden studs. The guy said that is not an issue and replaced the wall without touching the stud.
I think that's a load bearing wall. I am concerned about that little vertical split on the very bottom of the stud and considering having the wall removed again and have someone else look at it. What types of splits or cracks are ok on the studs?
This wall is the continuous of the bedroom wall that separates the two units of the condo.

A picture will help, but small splits are common.  Quite a few studs that are toe nailed will have them.  If you cannot push a pointy thing by hand into wood, it should okay.

I dont know how to add a pic here , does it have that feature

A pic is moot if we can't see the split, and as others said small splits are common. Your wall will not fall down because one stud has a small split.

I was reading that splits on the very buttom of the studs where it is connected to the horizontal wood underneath of them (and then connected to the ground) are more of a concerns than the ones in the middle of the stud

Where were you reading this? I've been building, remodeling, and improving homes for 40 years. A cracked stud means nothing unless it's in a critical location and is truly broken (crosswise).

@Mary, the internet is full of bad advice and misinformation about everything!  Accept the information you received here from people that are knowledgeable and experienced. As well as having your best interest in mind rather than just posting "Stuff" on their channel.

A split in one stud is never a concern. Walls are built to be a system of support. Wood is well known to contain flaws even when there isn't a split, and splits don't significantly reduce strength anyway.

Even if its on the very buttom of the stud?where it is connect to the the horizontal wood on the floor?

Also I am concerned that when they tried to drill the dry wall back on the studs, they might have cause more splits speciAlly to that one which slready had a little split

There are splits all over your wall. That's what wood does. It's not a problem.

Thank you for your responses i want to also ask ,1. the same stud that was connected to a wooden plate on the floor, it had a little angel with the edge of the plate as if the edges were not 100% aligning,  i tried to turn it and it moved very little but after that didnt move , it was a tiny circular move like 5 or 10 degree , is that a problem?i asked the maintanance person of the building to look at it, he couldn't move it and he said i dont know how you moved it.

Also when they were drilling and screwing back the new dry wall, could they have caused more damage to the stud?

You are obsessing over details I can't see. If you want further help, post clear photos in your question. Otherwise, move on. This is getting silly.
